# JavaScript checkbox toggle switch button alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on asp.net MVC-5, I have added a bootstrap toggle button using **checkbox** like bellow

My scripts

```
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-toggle.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-toggle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

My razor

**Note:** The bellow razor is placed in a partial view and is rendered in my layout
    @using (Html.BeginForm())   {
      @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
       @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

```
<fieldset style="height:60px">
    <legend style="text-align:center;  font-size:large; font-family:'Times     New Roman'; background-color:#C8E6C9; color:red">Remote On/Off</legend>
    <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle">
</fieldset>}
```

I want to add a simple alert on toggle switch button i.e. it will show me **On** alert while switching to On and **Off** alert while switching to off

I have searched many articles but couldn't find proper answer

**Update**

If have added id field in my input field and then passed it to the JS script like bellow and it's started working

```
<input id="test_id" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle">
$("#test_id").on("change", function (event) {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        alert("on");
    } else {
        alert("off");
    }
});
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add change event handler for the checkbox -

```
$("checkbox").on("change", function(event) {
     if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        alert("on");         
     } else {
        alert("off");
     }
});
```

Comment: Do you have any other checkbox on the page. If yes, you have to select the specific checkbox. Above code assumes you have only one checkbox on the page